# Argument of type 'void' is not assignable when using forkJoin() on imported service methods in an Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscription

I'm trying to send three sets of data from three different API get requests to an Angular component. Currently, I have a service that handles the HTTP requests and I import that service into my component so I can access the service methods.

I can currently subscribe to and return data for any single task-service method, doing this:

```
    this.tasksService.getTasks();
    this.tasksSub = this.tasksService.getTaskUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((allTasks: Task[]) => {
        this.allTasks = allTasks;
      });
```

`console.log(allTasks)` will return the desired result.

However, I need to get data from three different methods into my component and I cannot. This is my most recent of many attempts at using `forkJoin()` to accomplish this:

```
    this.tasksSub = forkJoin(
      this.tasksService.getTasks(),
      this.tasksService.getOpenTasks(),
      this.tasksService.getClosedTasks()
    ).this.tasksService.getTaskUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((allTasks: Task[], openTasks: Task[], closedTasks: Task[]) => {
        this.allTasks = allTasks;
        this.openTasks = openTasks;
        this.closedTasks = closedTasks;
      });
```

This block of code gives me this error message on the first parameter of `forkJoin()`:

[image: void error]

**Question:**
Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here is my entire component.ts and service.ts below:

**task-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

import { Task } from "../task.model";
import { TasksService } from "../tasks.service";
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: "app-task-list",
  templateUrl: "./task-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./task-list.component.css"]
})
export class TaskListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(public tasksService: TasksService, private authService: AuthService) {}

  allTasks: Task[] = [];
  openTasks: Task[] = [];
  closedTasks: Task[] = [];

  employeeIsAuthenticated = false;
  eId: string;
  isAdmin: string;

  private tasksSub: Subscription;
  private authStatusSub : Subscription;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.eId = this.authService.getEmployeeId();
    this.isAdmin = this.authService.getIsAdmin();


    this.tasksService.getTasks();
    this.tasksSub = this.tasksService.getTaskUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((allTasks: Task[]) => {
        this.allTasks = allTasks;
      });

    this.tasksSub = forkJoin(
      this.tasksService.getTasks(),
      this.tasksService.getOpenTasks(),
      this.tasksService.getClosedTasks()
    ).this.tasksService.getTaskUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((allTasks: Task[], openTasks: Task[], closedTasks: Task[]) => {
        this.allTasks = allTasks;
        this.openTasks = openTasks;
        this.closedTasks = closedTasks;
      });

    // auth sub
    this.employeeIsAuthenticated = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    this.authStatusSub = this.authService
      .getAuthStatusListener()
      .subscribe( isAuthenticated => {
        this.employeeIsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
        this.eId = this.authService.getEmployeeId();
        this.isAdmin = this.authService.getIsAdmin();
      });
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

  onDelete(taskId: string) {
    this.tasksService.deleteTask(taskId);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.tasksSub.unsubscribe();
    this.authStatusSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**tasks.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { Task } from "./task.model";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class TasksService {
  private tasks: Task[] = [];
  private tasksUpdated = new Subject<Task[]>();

  // we will need to construct this to use CRUD operations and router capabilities
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  // gets all tasks
  getTasks() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; tasks: any }>("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/alltasks")
      .pipe(
        map(taskData => {
          return taskData.tasks.map(task => {
            return {
              title: task.title,
              content: task.content,
              id: task._id,
              creator: task.creator,
              done: task.done
            };
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(transformedTasks => {
        console.log(transformedTasks);
        this.tasks = transformedTasks;
        this.tasksUpdated.next([...this.tasks]);
      });
  }
 // get tasks for single employee
  getMyTasks(creator: string) {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; tasks: any }>("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/mytasks/"+creator)
      .pipe(
        map(taskData => {
          return taskData.tasks.map(task => {
            return {
              title: task.title,
              content: task.content,
              id: task._id,
              creator: task.creator,
              done: task.done
            };
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(transformedTasks => {
        console.log(transformedTasks);
        this.tasks = transformedTasks;
        this.tasksUpdated.next([...this.tasks]);
      });
  }

  // get open tasks
  getOpenTasks() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; tasks: any }>("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/opentasks/")
      .pipe(
        map(taskData => {
          return taskData.tasks.map(task => {
            return {
              title: task.title,
              content: task.content,
              id: task._id,
              creator: task.creator,
              done: task.done
            };
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(transformedTasks => {
        console.log(transformedTasks);
        this.tasks = transformedTasks;
        this.tasksUpdated.next([...this.tasks]);
      });
  }

  // get closed tasks
  getClosedTasks() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; tasks: any }>("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/closedtasks/")
      .pipe(
        map(taskData => {
          return taskData.tasks.map(task => {
            return {
              title: task.title,
              content: task.content,
              id: task._id,
              creator: task.creator,
              done: task.done
            };
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(transformedTasks => {
        console.log(transformedTasks);
        this.tasks = transformedTasks;
        this.tasksUpdated.next([...this.tasks]);
      });
  }

  getTaskUpdateListener() {
    return this.tasksUpdated.asObservable();
  }
  // get specific task with id passed in
  getTask(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<{
      _id: string;
      title: string;
      content: string;
      creator: string;
      done: boolean;
      }>(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/" + id
    );
  }
  // create a task
  addTask(title: string, content: string, creator: string, done: boolean) {
    const task: Task = { id: null, title: title, content: content, creator: creator,  done: done};
    this.http
      .post<{ message: string; taskId: string }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/tasks",
        task
      )
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        const id = responseData.taskId;
        task.id = id;
        this.tasks.push(task);
        this.tasksUpdated.next([...this.tasks]);
        // return to tasks
        this.router.navigate(["/mytasks/"+creator]);
      });
  }
  // update a task
  updateTask(id: string, title: string, content: string, creator: string, done: boolean ) {
    const task: Task = { id: id, title: title, content: content, creator:creator, done: done };
    this.http
      .put("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/" + id, task)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const updatedTasks = [...this.tasks];
        const oldTaskIndex = updatedTasks.findIndex(t => t.id === task.id);
        updatedTasks[oldTaskIndex] = task;
        this.tasks = updatedTasks;
        this.tasksUpdated.next([...this.tasks]);
        // return to tasks
        this.router.navigate(["/mytasks/"+creator]);
      });
  }
 // delete a task
  deleteTask(taskId: string) {
    this.http
      .delete("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/" + taskId)
      .subscribe(() => {
        const updatedTasks = this.tasks.filter(task => task.id !== taskId);
        this.tasks = updatedTasks;
        this.tasksUpdated.next([...this.tasks]);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from `getTasks()`.

Comment: @martin `getTaskUpdateListener()` makes it an observable that can be subscribed to. I can access all of the data from `getTasks()` or any single method with that first block of code.

Answer (score 0):

The **forkJoin** accept only observables as parameters. Here in the scenario you show its not the case. To make this working, all the 3 methods in **TaskService** should return **Observables**. Please find the code snippet below:

In service file (TaskService):

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Post } from "../models/index";

@Injectable({
 providedIn: "root"
})
export class TaskService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

public getTasks() {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"; // URL just to demonstrate
  return this.http.get<Post[]>(url);
}
public getOpenTasks() {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"; // URL just to demonstrate
  return this.http.get<Post[]>(url);
}
public getClosedTasks() {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"; // URL just to demonstrate
  return this.http.get<Post[]>(url);
}
}
```

In Component:

```
constructor(private taskService:TaskService){}
ngOnInit(){
  forkJoin(
    this.taskService.getTasks(),
    this.taskService.getOpenTasks(),
    this.taskService.getClosedTasks(),
  ).subscribe(response=>{
    console.log(response);
  }, error=>{
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

Here the functions in service files is returning observables. And in the coomponent, we are making 3 parallel API calls and have a common subscription. We will get back the response as array. Please find below the demo urls:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sf-forkjoin-issue?file=src/app/app.component.ts

https://angular-sf-forkjoin-issue.stackblitz.io

Hope this will give you a clear understanding.

Comment: I have a method called `getTaskUpdateListener()` in my service which returns an observable object. I can subscribe to any one of the methods in my service using that. My very first block of code is where it is implemented and it works. Any way to use that method correctly to subscribe to all three of the methods I need? I do not want to rewrite my entire service and cause problems elsewhere in the app. I based this code on a tutorial by Maximilian Schwarzmüller found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tRLveSyNz8 he explains the code and  reasoning behind it around 2:19:40